# Headline: "YouTube创始人从雅虎手中收购Delicious". What is the purpose of "手中"

Tags: translation

If you take out 手中, isn't the translation, YouTube founder buys Delicious from Yahoo, still conveyed? What does 手中 add?

http://tech.sina.com.cn/i/2011-04-28/09065460713.shtml

Comment: I think it's emphasis. 手中 here emphasizes that Delicious was a part of Yahoo, firmly controlled by Yahoo, etc. A typical construction involving 手中 is `从他手中抢走了xx`, here the underlying message is that xx was firmly controlled by someone but grabbed by the other.

Comment: @user58955 That seems like a perfectly fine answer. Why not add it as an answer instead of a comment so you can get the appropriate credit?

Comment: 手中：someone takes the charge of sth, someone manages something, someone owns something.

Comment: I don't think it's emphasis. Removing `手中` doesn't just undo a emphasis meaning. It's totally weird to say `从他抢走了XX`

Answer (score 4):

手中 actually indicates somebody possess something.
For example B从A手中拿走C means A used to possess C and B take it from A, the sentence is to emphasize the action "take".

Answer (score 2):

Original:

`YouTube创始人从雅虎手中收购Delicious`

After removing `手中`:

`YouTube创始人从雅虎收购Delicious`

I don't think the second one sounds good. `手中` doesn't only express that Yahoo owns Delicious before the acquisition but also act as a complement to `雅虎`.

Thinking again, I don't think it's just an emphasis usage because `YouTube创始人从雅虎收购Delicious` sounds really weird. In Chinese `从` is looking for a noun for place not just a noun. A few examples:

`从北京得到的消息` - ok, because `北京` is a place

`从宾馆到机场` - ok , because `宾馆` is a place

`从张三那里得到的消息` is better than `从张三得到的消息` because `张三` is just a name not a place.

Answer (score -1):

1. “手中” means Delicious belonged to Yahoo, in this Headline the author treated Yahoo as a person (of cause a person with hands) —— Yahoo hold Delicious in his hands, and the creators of YouTube take Delicious from Yahoo's "hands".
2. “手中” 相当于“那里”（there）

“YouTube创始人从雅虎手中收购Delicious”
has the same meanig as 
“YouTube创始人从雅虎那里收购Delicious”